# Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ and let $S=\{x\in\mathbb{R}|f(x)=0\}$. If $(x_n)\in S$ & x=$\lim (x_n)$, show $x\in S$.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ and let $S=\{x\in\mathbb{R}|f(x)=0\}$ be the "zero set" of $f$. If $(x_n)$ in is $S$ and x=$\lim (x_n)$, show that $x\in S$.

By the Sequential Criterion for Continuity, we have that $(x_n)$ converges to $x$ so $f(x_n)$ converges to $f(x)$ since $f$ is continuous over $S$ $\Rightarrow$ $f$ is continuous at $(x_n)\in S$ $\Rightarrow$ $f$ is continuous at $x=\lim(x_n)$.

That's all I've got. Any help would be great.

Comment: You have everything that you need. What is $f(x_n)$ for each $n\in\Bbb N$?

Comment: Since $(x_n)\in S$, then $(x_n)\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x_n)=0$.

Comment: Then $f(x_n)$ converges to $f(x)=0$. Then, by the problem statement, $x=\lim(x_n)\in S$ since $f(x)=0$. Thank you! ^_^

Comment: You’re welcome!